# Чтение структуры из файла

Tags: c#, структуры, io

Сегодня столкнулся с проблемой чтения структур из файла.

Считываю таким замечательным методом:

```
public T ReadStruct<T> (FileStream fs)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0,  Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)));
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T temp = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
    handle.Free();
    return temp;
}
```

Но сегодня я решил написать парсер для некого формата файла и столкнулся с такой структурой:

```
public struct aBc
{
    public int countChars;
    public char[] chars;
}
/* Это отрезок от всей структуры. Она намного больше */
```

Длина массива `chars` равна `countChars`. Чтобы указать длину массива я делал так:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=128)]
public int[] test;
```

В этом случае вместо `128` я вписываю  `countChars`, но компилятор выдает ошибку. Значение должно быть заранее известно. Как поступить в таком случае?

Comment: покажите ваш код

Comment: А чем вам не угодила обычная сериализация\десериализация?

Comment: Какой-то низкоуровневый ужас. Чем вам BinaryReader не угодил?

Comment: Раз уж у вас низкоуровневый код, то может подойдёт fixed array в unsafe структуре? А как насчёт вынести часть кода в библиотеку на C++/CLI? И покажите формат файла, для которого пишете парсер.

Comment: @VladD, писать с нуля десериализацию объекта, используя BinaryReader - как раз и есть более низкоуровневое решение. В отличие от вызова Marshal.PtrToStructure(или других готовых десериализаторов), который получает тип с анотациями, указатель на память, и на выходе сразу даёт готовую структуру.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: Ну хотя бы [так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Но выделять нативную память, с которой не умеет нормально работать сборщик мусора, и использовать по сути аналог `reinterpret_cast` я бы в своём проекте побоялся.

Comment: @VladD, Как это решит поставленную задачу? Вы предлагаете человеку отказаться от существующего бинарного формата, и заменить это Binary/XML-сериализацией? Было бы замечательно, но это не всегда возможно.. Вероятней всего, формат этот уже давно в обращении, и никто не будет переписывать весь многочисленный парк ПО ради удобства одного-единственного C#-программиста.

Comment: @VladD, реализовать же полностью свои формат сериализации, позволяющий проводить (де-)сериализацию практически любых возможных структур с всевозможными типами данных - довольно трудоёмкая задача, которая в итоге приведет к написанию своего-собственного Marshal.PtrToStructure()

Comment: @VladD, на мой взгляд, это совсем не аналог reinterpret_cast - маршалинг вполне себе безопасен. По поводу выделения неуправляемой памяти - да, сборщик мусора не сможет нормально освободить её самостоятельно. Но автор вручную освобождает её в конце(хоть и не совсем правильно - всё, что идет после её выделения, следовало бы запихнуть в try, а Free() вызывать в finaly-блоке) - не привязанный к памяти хендл сборщик мусора вполне себе способен корректно убрать.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: В любом случае, низкоуровневое решение в сишном стиле через нативную память без типобезопасности кажется мне грубейшим хаком. Layout данных в файле не имеет права управлять layout'ом данных в памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо указания [SizeConst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeconst(v=vs.100).aspx), указывающего константное количество элементов в массиве, вам стоит использовать [SizeParamIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeparamindex(v=vs.100).aspx), указывающий индекс содержащего размер массива члена структуры(в вашем случае - `countChars` - `0`)